# How to validate the full version of current Rails in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How could we implement a method (eg. `rails_version?`) that be able to check the current Rails full version like this:

```rb
if rails_version?("6.0.3+") # return true if rails version >= 6.0.3.0
  # new way
else
  # old way
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Rails.version` to get the current version as a string.

However, that alone is not enough to compare it to other versions reliably. To do that, the best tool is `Gem::Version`.

```
Rails.version #=> "6.0.3.6"
Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) > Gem::Version.new('6.0.3.6') #=> false
Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) > Gem::Version.new('6.0.3') #=> true
Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) >= Gem::Version.new('6.0.3.6') #=> true
```

Though these would all work with strings as well, there are some cases that don't

```
Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) > Gem::Version.new('6.0.10') #=> false (correct)
Rails.version > '6.0.10' #=> true (incorrect)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```rb
def rails_version?(version)
 Rails::VERSION::STRING >= version
end
```